# Generate sequential membership number on Wordpress signup

Tags: php, wordpress, registration, membership

I have searched everywhere for a plugin that would generate a unique sequential membership number upon registration for Wordpress without any joy. Hopefully, other people out there would like this same functionality so with a bit of research and copying bits of code that I have found on the web have put together the following solution.

It is almost there but I would like to extend the functionality a bit more and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I would like to display the ID Number (Membership Number) on the WooCommerce my_account page as well as on some of the WooCommerce emails such as New Order and New Account emails.

I would also like to include a prefix to the 4 digit number that gets generated such as AU-0001 (AU can remain the same before each sequential number). Can I just add?...

```
<?php echo "AU-"$unique_number; ?>
```

The below code is working fine. It generates and shows the Membership Number in the User Profile list and User Profile Page after account creation.

If possible I would just like to add to the below code so that I am not modifying any core files that would get overridden when updating. The below code is in my functions.php file of my child theme.

Also, the //send email below sends the email with the text output but not the

```
strip_tags($user_id['my_unique_id'])
```

new Member Number. (This is not essential as I would rather not send a separate email but rather have the Member number show and send in the WooCommerce emails).

Thank you all in advance!

```
//create unique id on new user creation
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_on_user_register' );
function my_on_user_register( $user_id ) {
    $unique_id = + 1000 + $user_id;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_unique_id', $unique_id );
}
//display Membership Number on profile
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_extra_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_extra_user_profile_fields');
function my_extra_user_profile_fields($user){

    $unique_number = get_the_author_meta('my_unique_id', $user->ID);
?>
    <h3><?php _e('Membership Number'); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="address"><?php _e('Member Number:');   ?></label></th>
            <td><?php echo "AU-"$unique_number; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}
//send email with Membership Number to admin on new user registration
function registration_email_alert($user_id) {
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['user_login']). ' - ' . strip_tags($_POST['user_email']) . ' SMWS Membership Number: ' . strip_tags($user_id['my_unique_id']) . ' Has registered to the SMWS';
    wp_mail( 'your@email.com.au', 'New member has just registered', $message );
}
add_action('user_register', 'registration_email_alert');
//add Membership Number to user list
function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['my_unique_id'] = 'Membership Number';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );

function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'my_unique_id' :
            return get_the_author_meta( 'my_unique_id', $user_id );
            break;
        default:
    }
    return $return;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: why do you need to do this? there is already a unique id = user id , if you want to display it differently, you can just do something like `'unique'.$user_id`

Comment: This is how it works and what I am trying to achieve...
1. Visitor purchases membership through Woocommerce.
2. New member gets assigned a unique sequential Membership Number.
3. This number gets printed on a plastic VIP Membership Card and gets sent out.
4. This number is used for special coupon code offers as well as a number of off-line promotions and offers including membership identity.
5. The number should be displayed on their Profile page and My Account page as well as on Woocommerce emails.
This has all been implemented except for the issues above in my original question.